# LongListSelector Link event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I want to dynamically add more groups to a `LongListSelector` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection`.

When the `Link` event for the last group is called, I load more groups (that contain items).

The problem is, as soon as I add more groups to the `ObservableCollection` the items in the group wouldn't show anymore, only the group header shows for the newly added groups. I double checked that the `ObservableCollection` contains the correct groups and items.

It seems as if the `LongListSelector` gets flattened when more groups are added.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

---

EDIT: I also tried the following: In the link event of the last group, I set the `ItemsSource` of the `LongListSelector` to null, then I load the items and set the `ItemsSource` again:

```
    void LongListSelector_LinkEven(....)
    {
       ...

        if (currentGroup == _lastGrp)
        {
            myLongListSelector.ItemsSource = null;
            var items = LoadNextItems();
            myLongListSelector.ItemsSource = items;

        }
    }
```

This works, but when I scroll fastly, at some point the connection to the emulator gets lost, due to some serious error I guess.

I tried to catch the exception by setting the debugger to stop on all thrown Exception (handled and unhandled) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This article from [WindowsPhoneGeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios) may help you with your issue. Without being able to see additional code (like what type `items` is) I can't really help. However we were faced with a very similar problem (adding extra items and groups) and solved it by implementing the LongListSelector in the manner described in the link.

Let me know if you need additional information.

Cheers,
Alasdair.